# Python pd.read_csv: How to read files through a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I would like to be able to read data by using `pd.read_csv` and store the data in Numpy ndarrays. I have a set of data which includes elements as `xN1N1,xN1N2,...,xN1N50` (the general name format is as *xN1Ny*, `for y in range(2,51)`). For each of them, I basically would like to run the following operation:

```
xN1N1 = pd.read_csv("xN1N1.csv") 
xN1N1 = xN1N1.to_numpy()
```

To do this with a for loop (I would like to read and save all the elements at one time), I attempted to define a function that would help, as follows:

```
def data(id_number):
    x1 = pd.read_csv("'xN1N%d' % id_number.csv")
    return x1
```

Executing this `for y in range(2,51)` gives me nothing, I am aware that the syntax is extremely defected, but I cannot correct it.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: are all your csv in one folder ?

Comment: Try: `dfs = [pd.read_csv(f'xN1N{y}.csv') for y in range(2, 51)]`. Then you can access each dataframe by index, for example `dfs[10]`

Comment: @Datanovice, yes, they are in the same folder.

Comment: @Erfan thanks a lot! This solved the issue!

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck coding and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: @Erfan thanks a lot for your support! I strongly hope that I'll get better with the help of StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python string formatting to solve your problem.

```
return pd.read_csv("xN1N{}.csv".format(id_number))
```